# How to add and use a Web Service in Microsoft CRM 4.0?

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have my custom web service. I want to use it inside a "create account" form. I'm using the "**RemoteCommand**" js library to use it. But i can't reference my web service because "RemoteCommand" look for my web service in: "**AppWebServices\MyService.asmx**". How can I customize this path? Does exist any other way to integrate my web service in Microsoft CRM 4.0?

Comment: Are you aware that RemoteCommand is not supported?  And that it is for MS internal use only?

Answer (score 1):

The `RemoteCommand` is not part of the public SDK.

See how to [Access Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc150839.aspx) in Form Scripts.